# For the equation $z^3 = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta = \mathop{\rm{cis}}\theta$, prove that the sum of the roots is always $0$

Tags: complex-numbers, alternative-proof

Let:$$z^3 = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta = \mathop{\mathrm{cis}}\theta$$ prove that the sum of the three roots is always zero regardless of $\theta$. I've already proved it, but in a very long proof, about 6 - 7 lines, and during it sometimes the expression ran over the page. I won't bother writing it but will describe briefly. What I did was I used De Moivre's theorem to find the three solutions for z. Then I summed the solutions together, in doing so, I applied the compound angle rule for the two solutions where the argument was $(\theta/3) + (2\pi/3)$ and $(\theta/3) + (4\pi/3)$. Parts of the expression containing $\cos(2\pi/3)$ and other likewise parts were able to be simplified, but it was still a long expression that eventually cancelled out leaving $0$ as the answer. The proof took me over 10 minutes and was very tiresome. I've looked for a long time and I don't see any quicker or simpler way to prove it. I checked the book I used for the answer and it turns out 'proof' was written as the answer. Uh. So I couldn't compare my proof to the authors. If there's anyone that can help me out, much would be appreciated. The book is called Level 3 Calculus study guide, published by ESA, written by Frances Hinchliffe and Tom Sidebotham. It's a New Zealand book written for the NZ curriculum. The question can be found at the end of page 169 if anyone happens to have the book on hand. If anyone would like me to show my proof, I would gladly do so, however, it would be very long!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Which roots are you talking about?

Comment: The solutions for z. If there's more than one meaning for roots I'll be happy to know, but in this case, it refers to solutions (roots) for a polynomial equation form a high school perspective.

Comment: What I specified was what the question on the page was exactly written. The modulus is 1, but the argument is a variable. That's why they ask you to prove it regardless of theta.

Comment: Yes, so I'll delete comment.

Comment: I mean it could be $z^3 = 1$ if the argument happened to be a multiple of $2\pi$ but argument is variable so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By de Movire's theorem, the three roots are $\mathop{\mathrm{cis}}(\frac{\theta+2\pi n}{3})$ for $n=0,1,2$. Using the [sum-to-product formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities), the sum is

\begin{align*}
    \sum_{n=0}^2\mathop{\mathrm{cis}}(\tfrac{\theta+2\pi n}{3})&=\cos\tfrac\theta3+\cos(\tfrac{\theta+2\pi}3)+\cos(\tfrac{\theta+4\pi}3)+i\big(\sin\tfrac\theta3 + \sin(\tfrac{\theta+2\pi}3)+\sin(\tfrac{\theta+4\pi}3)\big)\\
&= \cos(\tfrac{\theta+2\pi}3)-2\cos(\tfrac{\theta+2\pi}3)\cos(\tfrac{4\pi}{3}) + i\big(\sin(\tfrac{\theta+2\pi}3)-2\sin(\tfrac{\theta+2\pi}3)\cos(\tfrac{4\pi}{3})\big)\\
&=0,
\end{align*}
as required.

Comment: Oh my, I forgot about my sums and products identities, damn it would've been way easier. Thanks, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your book to hand, but I suspect their proof goes something like this:

The sum of the roots of the polynomial $az^3+bz^2+cz+d$ is just $-b/a$. In your polynomial, $a=1$ and $b=0$.

**Edited to respond to the comment from medstudent-no.4838:**

The root sum formula comes from multiplying out $$P(z)=az^3+bz^2+cz+d=a(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)(z-\gamma)$$
where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the roots of $P$. You will find that the coefficient of $z^2$ is
$$a(-\alpha-\beta-\gamma)$$
Therefore
$$b=a(-\alpha-\beta-\gamma)$$

Comment: How did you know that the sum of the roots is $-d/a$?

Comment: The sum of roots is $-b/a$, not $-d/a$ (that would be the product).

Comment: @LukeCollins: Whoops! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @medstudent-no.4838 Follows by the fundamental theorem of algebra if you are familiar with it. If not, see an alternate proof in my answer.

Comment: @medstudent-no.4838: I have edited my answer.

Comment: In that book I mentioned, the only thing it taught me was that the fundamental theorem of algebra states that for the polynomial, $f(x) = 0$, then it has n roots, some may be repeated.